# Make an probablity relationship easier

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

If $X$ and $Y$ and $Z$ are independent random variables and $C$ is a fixed value, is the relationship below true?
$$\text{Pr} \left\lbrace X+\min \left( Y,Z \right) <C\bigg\vert Z \geq C \right\rbrace = \text{Pr}  \left\lbrace  X+Y < C  \right\rbrace $$ 
My proof is shown below:
$$\text{Pr} \left\lbrace X+\min \left( Y,Z \right) <C\bigg\vert Z \geq C \right\rbrace = \text{Pr} \left\lbrace X+Y<C \, \cup \, X+Z<C \bigg\vert  Z \geq C \right\rbrace= \text{Pr}  \left\lbrace  X+Y<C \bigg\vert  Z \geq C \right\rbrace = \text{Pr}   \left\lbrace X+Y<C  \right\rbrace$$

Comment: How do you prove the second equality? Z > C does not contradict X+Z < C, only if you require X to be nonnegative.

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ and $Z$ are nonnegative random variables.

Comment: Aha, so why you don't state this? Then the proof is correct.

Comment: I am sorry because I have involved in this proof so much. I forgot to write it. Anyway is my proof under this condition true?

Answer (score 0):

Let $Y = 1, Z = 0 = C$. Then you ask if $\Pr(X<0) = \Pr(X+1<0)$.

Comment: Your answer has no business to my question.

Comment: Why? Basically, I gave an counterexample.